# MySQL, JSON and Fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, fullcalendar

I am working to integrate MySQL events in Fullcalendar.

I've read many guide/post but i can't import events from a json script.
Now, if I paste the JSON result of "myfeed.php" in fullcalendar, my calendar works and it include all events. If I link fullcalendar to myfeed.php, the calendar is empty. I've tried, also, to link my calendar to fullcalendar's "get-events.php" (that should work with myfeed.php), but the calendar is always empty. :/

this is my **fullcalendar**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
              },
              editable: true,
              eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
              events: {
                  url: 'fullcalendar/php/get-events.php',
                  //url: 'fullcalendar/myfeed.php',
                  error: function() {
                      $('#script-warning').show();
                  }
              },
              loading: function(bool) {
                  $('#loading').toggle(bool);
              }
          });

      });
```

this is the **result of myfeed.php**:

```
[{“id”:”1″,”title”:”allenamentosimone”,”allDay”:”false”,”start”:”1423036800″,”end”:”1423044000″,”url”:”pippo”},
{“id”:”2″,”title”:”allenamentodue”,”allDay”:”true”,”start”:”1423310400″,”end”:”1423335600″,”url”:”pluto”}]
```

and **myfeed.php** is [visible on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/e1eDpqRh)
(for the site jsonformatter the result is a valid json, but the file isn't a valid json).

Any suggestion?

---

**UPDATE**:

I've changed the event url in: 
`url: 'fullcalendar/myfeed.php'`

Also, i've changed the date format of my json in *YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS* and now i can see my events on fullcalendar. However I see all events in all day mode :/

This is the new json returnment:

```
[
{"id":"1","title":"allenamentosimone","allDay":"false","start":"2015-02-04 09:00:00","end":"2015-02-04 11:00:00","url":"pippo"},
{"id":"2","title":"allenamentodue","allDay":"true","start":"2015-02-07 13:00:00","end":"2015-02-07 20:00:00","url":"pluto"}
]
```

---

**UPDATE N.2**:

If i don't write anything in allDay section, my fullcalendar works perfectly! This is the last json returnment:

```
[
{"id":"1","title":"allenamentosimone","allDay":"","start":"2015-02-04 09:00:00","end":"2015-02-04 11:00:00","url":"pippo"},
{"id":"2","title":"allenamentodue","allDay":"true","start":"2015-02-07 13:00:00","end":"2015-02-07 20:00:00","url":"pluto"}
]
```

Comment: i think it's because allDay is not string, it's boolean. don't use quotes around true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`events` should be single url to feed from database.

So replace events like this:

```
events: 'fullcalendar/php/get-events.php',
```

**Check in browser inspector if it tries to reach DB file.** In Chrome it opens with Ctrl+Shift+i and navigate to `Network` tab. Database URL is relative from browser url where you use it.

For example, if you have page `testfullcalnedar.io/mycalendar`
And lets say your php is located on `testfullcalnedar.io/mycalendar/fullcalendar/php/get-events.php'`.

Then in script events feed URL would be `fullcalendar/php/get-events.php` OR `/mycalendar/fullcalendar/php/get-events.php`

**Explanation** - if you begin feed URL with `/` it will start search it from root of your domain else it will search relative to location where script is. In my example case script runs under `testfullcalnedar.io/mycalendar`

Comment: Ok, i've changed the url in:
url: 'fullcalendar/myfeed.php' (that return the json)
Also, i've changed the date format of my json in YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS and now i can see my events on fullcalendar. however I see all events in all day mode :/

Comment: Good! I've found the problem. If i don't write anything in allDay section, my fullcalendar works perfectly!

Comment: `allDay` is meant to change default event settings. It applies to each event individually and takes precedence when event has NOT set `allDay` propery. [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/) has very well documenation.

If above is correct, please, mark this as answered :)